# Send string values from activity to fragment using Bundle returns null

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-bundle

I have a bottom navigation bar with 4 menu items the user can pick. Depending on what they pick determines which fragment is shown in my frame. I can get the fragments to load and can interact with them. But I also need to send some string values to each fragment, but can't figure out where I have gone wrong. When I start my fragment and try to access my values with getArguments(), it always comes back null.  Below is my code:

unitactivity.java where I run through my code for choosing the fragment

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class UnitActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private BottomNavigationView bottomNavigation;
    private Fragment fragment;
    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;

    Boolean CheckEditText;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    String ReadOnly;
    String LexaUser;
    String Password;
    String QA;
    String SearchValue;
    String UnitId;
    String UnitSize;
    String UnitStatus;

    Button UnitDetailsHeader;
    TextView UnitSizeText;
    TextView UnitStatusText;

    String finalResultUnitDetails;
    String HttpURLUnitDetails = "https://[path/to/server]/getUnitDetails.php";
    HashMap<String, String> hashMapUnitDetails = new HashMap<>();
    HttpParse httpParse = new HttpParse();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_units);

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        LexaUser = intent.getStringExtra("UserName");
        ReadOnly = intent.getStringExtra("ReadOnly");
        Password = intent.getStringExtra("Password");
        QA = intent.getStringExtra("QA");
        SearchValue = intent.getStringExtra("SearchInput");

        bottomNavigation = (BottomNavigationView)findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
        bottomNavigation.inflateMenu(R.menu.bottom_menu);
        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        bottomNavigation.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);

        UnitDetailsHeader = findViewById(R.id.UnitDetailsViewTitle);
        UnitDetailsHeader.setText(SearchValue);

        UnitSizeText = findViewById(R.id.UnitSize);
        UnitStatusText = findViewById(R.id.UnitStatus);

        if (SearchValue.contains("-")) {
            getUnitDetails(SearchValue, LexaUser);
        } else {
            getSiblings();
        }

        bottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                int id = item.getItemId();

                switch (id){
                    case R.id.action_search:
                        fragment = new NewUnitStatusFragment();
                        break;
                    case R.id.action_cart:
                        fragment = new PendingUnitStatusFragment();
                        break;
                    case R.id.action_hot_deals:
                        fragment = new FinalUnitStatusFragment();
                        break;
                    case R.id.action_siblings:
                        fragment = new SiblingUnitFragment();
                        break;
                }

                Bundle connBundle = new Bundle();
                connBundle.putString("SearchValue", SearchValue);
                connBundle.putString("LexaUser", LexaUser);
                connBundle.putString("Password", Password);
                connBundle.putString("QA", QA);

                fragment.setArguments(connBundle);

                final FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.main_container, fragment).commit();

                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And when I try to access the values in my fragment: (onCreateView)

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Bundle bundle = getArguments();

    if (bundle != null) {
        SearchValue = bundle.getString("SearchValue");
        LexaUser = bundle.getString("LexaUser");
        Password = bundle.getString("Password");
    }

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_newunitstatus, container, false);

    newUnitStatusContext = getContext();
    newUnitStatusActivity = getActivity();

    statusSpinner = view.findViewById(R.id.Status);
    generalCauseSpinner = view.findViewById(R.id.GeneralCause);
    newUSComment = view.findViewById(R.id.NewComment);
    newUnitStatusImage = view.findViewById(R.id.AddPhoto);
    addPhotoBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.AddPhotosLabel);
    addNewUnitStatus = view.findViewById(R.id.addBtnNewUnitStatus);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> statusSpinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(newUnitStatusContext,
            R.array.new_unit_status_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

    statusSpinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    statusSpinner.setAdapter(statusSpinnerAdapter);

    newUnitStatus = statusSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> generalCauseSpinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(newUnitStatusContext,
            R.array.status_general_cause_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

    generalCauseSpinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    generalCauseSpinner.setAdapter(generalCauseSpinnerAdapter);

    generalCause = generalCauseSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

    addPhotoBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
                startGallery();
        }
    });

    // Set a click listener for the text view
    addNewUnitStatus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            newUnitStatus = statusSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            generalCause = generalCauseSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            newUnitStatusComment = newUSComment.getText().toString();

            Toast.makeText(newUnitStatusContext, "SV: " +SearchValue + " US: " + newUnitStatus + " GC: " + generalCause + " USC: " + newUnitStatusComment + " User: " + LexaUser + " PW: " + Password, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            //addNewUnitStatus(SearchValue, newUnitStatus, generalCause, newUnitStatusComment, newUnitStatusPhoto, LexaUser, Password);

        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

All help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Are you pretty sure, that before creating the instance for new fragment, you have already filled that variables `SearchValue, LexaUser, Password, QA`. What if you in that activity didn't receive the variables from that Bundle?

Comment: Sry, I didn't include it in my code but I actually have a call to a function I make called getUnitDetails() that uses the same values and those work just fine...

Comment: Put a breakpoint in your IDE at fragment.setArguments(connBundle); Debug and walk it and check if the bundle is being passed correctly.

Comment: Are variable assigned correctly in the activity? Did you debug it?

Comment: So far, i've run through debugging steps for opening my fragment. I can see my variables in my UnitActivity class but they stay null for the fragment itself.

Comment: You're saying that after strings were bundled, your connBundle in UnitActivity when passed to the fragment instance is not null correct?

Comment: No thats the issue, they are null.... But I can't figure out how I'm doing the bundle wrong... However, I'm wondering if its an issue of sending the same bundle to 4 different menu items depending on what is clicked in the navigation bar?

Comment: oh man.... How silly of me.... My code fires off with the onClickListener for the buttomNavigationBar. The reason the bundle is null is because this screen is the default view when starting the UnitActivity.java class in most scenarios. This means I need to send my information to make fragment then too... ugh silly mistake...

Answer (score 0):

For an alternative answer, you can try the following:

```
bottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                int id = item.getItemId();

                Bundle connBundle = new Bundle();
                connBundle.putString("SearchValue", SearchValue);
                connBundle.putString("LexaUser", LexaUser);
                connBundle.putString("Password", Password);
                connBundle.putString("QA", QA);

                switch (id){
                    case R.id.action_search:
                        fragment = new NewUnitStatusFragment(connBundle);
                        break;
                    case R.id.action_cart:
                        fragment = new PendingUnitStatusFragment(connBundle);
                        break;
                    case R.id.action_hot_deals:
                        fragment = new FinalUnitStatusFragment(connBundle);
                        break;
                    case R.id.action_siblings:
                        fragment = new SiblingUnitFragment(connBundle);
                        break;
                }

                final FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.main_container, fragment).commit();

                return true;
            }
        });
```

Within your Fragment, you get arguments from the passed bundle parameter, for example:

```
private Bundle bundle;

    public static FragmentA(Bundle bundle) {
        this.bundle = bundle;
    }

 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if (bundle != null) {
        SearchValue = bundle.getString("SearchValue");
        LexaUser = bundle.getString("LexaUser");
        Password = bundle.getString("Password");
    }

    //etc...
}
```